# Generics mess with IBindingList and BindingList<T>

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm working on a small library which is basically a live linq. I should be able to do stuff like this:

```
var list1 = new BindingList<int>();
ReadOnlyBindingList<int> live = list1.LiveSelect(i => i + 1);
```

Here, `ReadOnlyBindingList` is a generic abstract class I wrote that implements `IBindingList` but doesn't inherit `BindingList<T>`. The `LiveSelect` method takes a `BindingList<T>` list and returns a class that implements the `ReadOnlyBindingList<T>` abstract class. Now I want to be able to do:

```
ReadOnlyBindingList<int> live = list1.LiveSelect(i => i + 1).LiveSelect(i => i * i);
```

But in order to do this, my `LiveSelect` would need to either take a `ReadOnlyBindingList<T>`, which would force me to add an extension method `AsReadOnly` that would take a `BindingList<T>` and wrap it into a class that inherits from `ReadOnlyBindingList<T>`, so my code would look like:

```
ReadOnlyBindingList<int> live = list1.AsReadOnly().Select(i => i + 1).Select(i => i * i);
```

Or have `LiveSelect` take an `IBindingList` and be forced to add casts everywhere from `object` to `TResult` and also make the compiler unable to infer the type from usage when I concatenate more than one `LiveSelect`, such that my code would need to look like this:

```
var live = list.LiveSelect(i => i + 1).LiveSelect<int, int>(i => i + 1);
```

Is there any way I can make my code look like this:

```
var live = list.LiveSelect(i => i + 1).LiveSelect(i => i + 1);
```

where `list` is a `BindingList<int>`?

Comment: Why the decision not to derive ReadingBindingList<T> from BindingLit<T>? It seems that this decision is behind your difficulties.

Comment: Because that would make the list non read-only. Right now, all write operations throw an exception. The actual name is `ReadOnlyBindingList`.

Comment: So override the methods to throw exceptions. That's got to be less work than  rewriting the whole class.

Comment: I don't think they're virtual are they?

Comment: ClearItems() is. Didn't check any others.

Comment: Many are not, such as `this[int index]` which the way my class is right now I'd need to override because items are not stored straight into the list but inside a wrapper. So my `this[int index]` actually looks like `return _Items[index].Result`. I could still rewrite the whole class but then the users would still be able to mess with data they're not supposed to by writing stuff like `((IList)myReadOnlyList)[0] = null`.

Comment: My first thought would be to write the LiveSelect method as an extension method to IEnumerable<int> - as long as ReadingBindingList and BindingList both inherit from that.

Comment: why not add a LiveSelect to your ReadOnlyBindingList that makes the cast?

Answer (score 0):

why not add a LiveSelect to your ReadOnlyBindingList that makes the casts or the needed convertions internally?

```
var live = list.LiveSelect(i=> i+1)/*this returns a readonlybindinglist*/.LiveSelect(i=> i+1)/*this is the method in bindinglist*/

public ReadOnlyBindingList<T> LiveSelect(Func<T,T> lambda){
  return /* call static method that does liveselect */
}
```

and this is the extension

```
public static ReadOnlyBindingList<T> LiveSelect(this BindingList<T> source, Func<T,T> lamda){
   return /*cast to readonlybindinglist and call static method that does liveselect */
}
```